# Improve CoreNLP POS tagger and NER tagger?

Tags: java, nlp

The CoreNLP parts of speech tagger and name entity recognition tagger are pretty good out of the box, but I'd like to improve the accuracy further so that the overall program runs better. To explain more about accuracy -- there are situations in which the POS/NER is wrongly tagged. For instance:

- "Oversaw car manufacturing" gets tagged as NNP-NN-NN

Rather than VB* or something similar, since it's a verb-like phrase (I'm not a linguist, so take this with a grain of salt).

So what's the best way to accomplish accuracy improvement?

- Are there better models out there for POS/NER that can be incorporated into CoreNLP?
- Should I switch to other NLP tools?
- Or create training models with exception rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "Oversaw car manufacturing" is not even a sentence and on its own does not make much sense :-) These models are most often trained on whole sentences. If you enter "He oversaw car manufacturing" here [1], which is using CoreNLP, then you get a more sane result.

Let's assume though that you still have inaccurate results. Unless you're using some small example model there's no "better" model per se. It always depends on the domain, and even the "default" models are trained on certain domains, e.g. newspapers.

Most likely you will have to train a model yourself, not with exception rules, but for a specific domain of text, e.g. texts talking about cars or about manufacturing, or with a certain style of writing, etc.

[1] http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

Comment: do you have any best practices for training the model? How should I pick and choose the data? Should it be balanced somehow?